# How to Create Dynamic Column Name push data stored in dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Daily Changing Column Name
>      YEARS,model1,model2,model3,model4,model5,model6  Change Random Column
>      Names  YEARS,model9,model8,model1,model4,model2,model10

```
var Data=[{"YEARS":"2012","model1":"6","model2":"2","model3":"0","model4":"0","model5":"0","model6":"0"}]
```

Here My Static Column Name -

```js
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  Model1.push(Data[i].model1);
  Model2.push(Data[i].model2);
  Model3.push(Data[i].model3);
  Model4.push(Data[i].model4);
  Model5.push(Data[i].model5);
  Model6.push(Data[i].model6);
  Allyears.push(Data[i].YEARS);
}
```

Dynamic column name push and variables

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: for me, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i am tried  dynamic column  using push not working but i worked static column name using push worked